# Allocate memory to a specific location

Tags: c, macos, memory

Is there any way to allocate memory at a specific location in 64-bit macOS? Specifically, can you allocate to the lower 32-bit address space (i.e. the first 4 GiB of memory)? I tried to use `mmap` with the `MAP_FIXED` flag and it would never successfully allocate any memory to the first 4 GiB, but adding `0x200000000` to the location before allocating let it always work (but obviously is not within the 32-bit space).

Comment: I am not aware of a userspace mechanism to reliably accomplish what you ask.  `mmap()` was your best bet as far as I am aware, but its use for the purpose is a bit fraught, and `mmap()` is in any case not bound to honor a requested address when one is specified (even with `MAP_FIXED`, it can fail instead).  Why do you want to place the mapping at a specific address?

Comment: I was trying to write a Linux compatibility layer, but all of the addresses in the ELF were in the lower 32 bits.

Comment: ELF objects are relocatable.  As far as I am aware, they do not map symbols to specific addresses, and I don't know how they could, because they are compatible with ASLR on both Linux and Mac.  I suspect you are misinterpreting something.

Comment: This somehow smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I thought that the virtual address associated with a program or section header was where the memory for it needed to be allocated in its own address space.

Comment: With the XY problem potential, should I change the question to ask how to allocate memory for an ELF file or something like that?

Comment: I am uncertain exactly what you mean by "the virtual address associated with a program or section header", but I can nevertheless give a confident "no" to that.  ELF shared objects do not pre-define addresses for the objects and functions within.  A base address or addresses are chosen to the time the object is dynamically loaded, on a per-process basis.

Comment: I meant the virtual address specified in the program header or section header.
One of my test ELFs seems to have a hard-coded address, and it fails to execute properly if I move the memory allocation away from the specified address.

Comment: What you should do is read [Drepper's paper on ELF objects](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf).  It is somewhat Linux-focused, but for the most part, ELF is the same on all platforms that use it.  As a bonus, it discusses why one of the design goals for ELF was that it not rely on fixed load addresses.